# Interesting vector valued functions $\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$

Tags: functions, vectors

I am working on a project which essentially involves me generating high dimensional vectors which evolve smoothly (Lipschitz) over a finite time interval. I am trying to come up with 'interesting' vector valued functions $f:\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$, in a similar flavor to the way that
$$g(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\sin t\\\cos t\end{bmatrix}$$

is an interesting function.

My trouble is that it's not hard to come up with cases where $p=2,3$ but for something like $p=100$ it is less clear.

One thing I have considered is something along the lines of

$$g(t)=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}_t$$

where $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ is a constant coefficient matrix and $\mathbf{X}_t$ is a vector of fourier basis functions (e.g. $\mathbf{X}_t=[\sin(t),\cos(t),\sin(2t),\cos(2t),\dots]^T$), although I wonder if another basis, or another form of $g(t)$ may do the trick better? Any thoughts/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how exactly you define "better" or more "interesting in that way. Could you clarify the purpose a bit?

Comment: And do you mean Lipschiz smoothly in the sense that it is differentiable and its derivative is Lipschitz continuous? So that it can be upper bounded by a quadratic function?

Comment: Yes differentiable and Lipschitz continuous derivative. By 'interesting' I guess I mean a function where there is some sort of nontrivial  dependence between the evolution of each of the coordinates.